# Stopping tcpdump spawned in bash script

Tags: bash, process, kill, busybox

I'm working with a BusyBox enviroment and I have a scheduling script which checks some conditions; on some, it starts `sniff.sh` in the background which itself calls `tcpdump` with some arguments. Now when I use `pidof sniff.sh` and `kill` that PID, `tcpdump` still runs in the background.

How can I kill tcpdump without finding it's PID manually?

Comment: Good question lol, I had a similar experience recently but got distracted before finding the answer 

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to kill by name with

```
pkill tcpdump
```

Or to kill process by Id

```
kill -9 $(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump)
```

Comment: Neither `pkill` nor the `-e` flag for `ps` is available for me :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured this works flawless:

```
tcpdump_pid=$(pidof tcpdump)
kill $tcpdump_pid
```